# Do an UIViewController that don't use the full screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I'want to do an UIViewController that don't use the full screen. The purpose is to put this view controller always on the top of other views. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the width and length of the view in the xib/nib. Then with set it as a subview to your view.

```
[self.view addSubview:yourViewController];
```

this should do the job.

Comment: If you create a view in interface builder but you seem unable to change the width and height for that view, set the status bar to none first.